# Dynamic form using AngularJS, multiple values binding

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am looking for a best approach to convert a static form to an angular dynamic form. I am not sure how to bind multiple values to the same answer.

The static page is available at: https://jsfiddle.net/hvuq5h46/

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
     <select ng-model="i.answer" ng-options="o.id as o.title for o in i.answersAvailable" ng-visible="y.TYPE = 'SINGLE'"></select>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.answer" ng-visible="y.TYPE = 'MULTIPLE'" />
</div>
```

The JSON file

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Are you a student?",
    "type": "SINGLE",
    "answersAvailable": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "No"
      }
    ],
    "answer": [
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Would you like to be an astronaut?",
    "type": "SINGLE",
    "answersAvailable": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "No"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "I am not sure"
      }
    ],
    "answer": [
      4
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "What is your favourite planet?",
    "type": "MULTIPLE",
    "answersAvailable": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Earth"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "title": "Mars"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "Jupiter"
      }
    ],
    "answer": [
      7,
      8
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things would be much simpler if you can use a multiple select, but I understand it might be difficult for user to interact (consider something like [md-select](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select), which transforms multiple select into a list of checkbox for you)

Multiple select:

```
<select multiple
  ng-model="i.answer"
  ng-options="o.id as o.title for o in i.answersAvailable"
  ng-if="i.type == 'MULTIPLE'"></select>
```

Anyway it is completely ok to use HTML checkbox. To do that we would need to bind checkbox model into the data as usual, and then update the answer array simultaneously.

`ng-model="o.selected"`

`ng-change="updateAnswer(i)"`

Also, we'll need to copy existing data to model during init.

`ng-init="initMultiple(i)"`

Working code:

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', Test);

function Test($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Are you a student?",
      "type": "SINGLE",
      "answersAvailable": [{
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Yes"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "No"
        }
      ],
      "answer": [
        1
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Would you like to be an astronaut?",
      "type": "SINGLE",
      "answersAvailable": [{
          "id": 4,
          "title": "Yes"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "title": "No"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "title": "I am not sure"
        }
      ],
      "answer": [
        4
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "What is your favourite planet?",
      "type": "MULTIPLE",
      "answersAvailable": [{
          "id": 7,
          "title": "Earth"
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "title": "Mars"
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "title": "Jupiter"
        }
      ],
      "answer": [
        7,
        8
      ]
    }
  ]
  
  $scope.initMultiple = function(item) {
    item.answersAvailable.forEach(function(option) {
      option.selected = item.answer.indexOf(option.id) != -1;
    });
  }
  
  $scope.updateAnswer = function(item) {
    item.answer = item.answersAvailable.filter(function(option) {
      return option.selected;
    })
    .map(function(option) {
      return option.id;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <div ng-repeat="i in items">
    <select ng-model="i.answer[0]"
      ng-options="o.id as o.title for o in i.answersAvailable"
      ng-if="i.type == 'SINGLE'"></select>

    <label ng-repeat="o in i.answersAvailable" 
      ng-if="i.type == 'MULTIPLE'"
      ng-init="initMultiple(i)">

      <input type="checkbox" 
        ng-model="o.selected" 
        ng-change="updateAnswer(i)" /> {{o.title}}
    </label>
    <div>{{i.answer}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. You've helped a lot. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, I will make a separation as two Angular models (or usually called services) for the form questions and another one which will collect the answers and eventually will be passed to the backend for further processing. This will provide me a flexibility to maintain both logic and presentation.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []); 
myModule.factory('QuestionsFormService', function() {
  var _question1;
  var _question2;
  var _question3;

  function init(data){
     //questions initiation
  }

   return init;
});

var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []); 
myModule.factory('FormDataService', function() {
   var _dataAnswer = {}

   function init(){
      //data initialization
   }

   function insertData(key, value){
      _dataAnswer[key] = value
   }
   return init;
});
```

From the example of service models above, you need to make these available to your presentation through the Angular controller with Dependency Injection.

```
myModule.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, FormDataService, QuestionsFormService) {
  $scope.form_questions = QuestionsFormService.init();
  $scope.form_answers = FormDataService.init()
  //further logic to make these available on your view on your convenience
});
```

What you write on the HTML page as an Angular view is already close enough. You only need to change the binding to two models as I propose above. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, however the form will be dynamic. For instance sometimes it must show a checkbox collections or a combobox. The problem could be solved using a different approach indeed. I am just trying to figure out how to bind to a dropdown list multiple values.